# Toggle! Bang Change in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, toggle, persistence, rails-activerecord

Trying to solve a mystery for the purpose of documentation.
We're upgrading from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.

In the Rails 3.2 code, we have (well, had):

```
def update_object_special_eligibility
  object.toggle!(:can_run_on_special) if object && object.can_run_on_special? && ineligible_for_special?
end
```

I realize this doesn't give you all the information you need, but here is the error. You should know that `can_run_on_special` is a bitfield rather than an official attribute, though I don't think it's actually relevant. Just thought I'd let you know why we were getting the error:

```
1) Error:
ObjectStatusTest#test_should_mark_object_as_not_eligible_to_run_on_special_for_specific_unschedule_reasons:

ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute     `can_run_on_special'
    config/initializers/acts_as_audited.rb:280:in `write_attribute_with_audit'
    app/models/object_status.rb:437:in `update_deal_amazon_eligibility'
    test/unit/object_status_test.rb:481:in `block in <class:ObjectStatusTest>'
    test/fast_test_helper.rb:99:in `call'
    test/fast_test_helper.rb:99:in `block in <class:TestCase>'
```

The code we changed it to that works on Rails 4:

```
def update_object_special_eligibility
  if object && object.can_run_on_special? && ineligible_for_special?
  object.update_attributes! :can_run_on_special => false
end
```

My suspicion is that because `toggle!` operates like `update_attribute` in terms of bypassing validations that it's just returning `false` for saving the attribute, and therefore, `toggle!` just doesn't work anymore because the updating of the attribute and the saving isn't working. But I am not sure that's the case. I'm hoping someone out here might have some idea about why this ActiveRecord::Persistence method (`toggle!`) might be operating differently in Rails 4. Or, is it the updating of the "attribute" and saving that is likely operating differently?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like acts_as_audited is getting in on the act, and isn't bitfield/toggle savvy, would be my guess. Too many cooks hacking in their wares here. (bitfield and acts_as_audited).